# Script to capture my find and correct second line

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program that captures the first and second lines of an input file based on a regex match.

In my input file, there are header breaks within the detail I need, and it is not capturing the line I want, so the second line of detail is not there.

Is it possible to alter my program to be able to capture the correct line of detail based on either whitespace or the location of the second line?

If it occurs the header split and second line is always in the same location throughout the file.

Below is the script I have so far, but as I mentioned it does not capture the second line as I want it to when the line has a header split within the detail.

```perl
use strict;

my $find  = '^(J0|JT)';
my $match = 0;

open( NEW,  ">", "output.txt" )   or die "could not open:$!";
open( FILE, "<", "combined.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;

    if ($match) {
        $match = 0;
        print NEW "$_\n";
    }

    if (/$find/) {
        $match = 1;
        print NEW "$_";
    }
}
close(FILE);
close(NEW);
```

###combined.txt

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JT00000000  DOE, JANE              01/23/16            J00000000    1    01/27/16
              U# NUMBER        UNIT #                                FAIL        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JT00000000  DOE, JOHN              01/24/16            J00000000    1    01/28/16

                             CLAIM DETAIL
                                                                          
PATIENT                           ADM/SER   DIS DATE  UNIT #       NUM  BILL DATE 
              CHECKS           DESCRIPTION                           VALUE (FIRST)
              TOB AFTER        UNIT #                                FAIL         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
J000000000  DOE, JOHN              01/25/16  01/31/16  J00000000    1    01/29/16 
              TXN MISS         UNIT #                                FAIL
```

###output.txt (required)

```
JT00000000  DOE, JANE              01/23/16            J00000000    1    01/27/16 U# NUMBER  UNIT #   FAIL                                      
JT00000000  DOE, JOHN              01/24/16            J00000000    1    01/28/16 TOB AFTER           FAIL                                      
J000000000  DOE, JOHN              01/25/16  01/31/16  J00000000    1    01/29/16 TXN MISS            FAIL
```

Comment: You're trying to process the output of a report program. That's always wrong: you should use the data directly from the same source that the report program uses

Answer (score 0):

This prints only the first and last lines between header breaks.  It keeps a buffer of all lines until the next break.  Note that I added a header break at the end.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^-/) {
        if (@lines) {
            print @lines[0, -1], "\n";
        }
        @lines = ();
    }
    else {
        push @lines, $_;
    }
}

__DATA__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JT00000000  DOE, JANE              01/23/16            J00000000    1    01/27/16
              U# NUMBER        UNIT #                                FAIL        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JT00000000  DOE, JOHN              01/24/16            J00000000    1    01/28/16

                             CLAIM DETAIL

PATIENT                           ADM/SER   DIS DATE  UNIT #       NUM  BILL DATE 
              CHECKS           DESCRIPTION                           VALUE (FIRST)
              TOB AFTER        UNIT #                                FAIL         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
J000000000  DOE, JOHN              01/25/16  01/31/16  J00000000    1    01/29/16 
              TXN MISS         UNIT #                                FAIL 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this. It simply skips every line that doesn't start with `J0` or `JT`, otherwise it prints the current line and reads and prints the following one

It's almost always simpler to write a program that reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT. That way you can test it by running

```
$ perl report.pl combined.txt
```

which will print the output to your console, or

```
$ perl report.pl combined.txt > output.txt
```

if you want to write the results to `output.txt` as your original program does

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <> ) {

    next unless /^J[0T]/;

    print;
    print scalar <>;
    print "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
JT00000000  DOE, JANE              01/23/16            J00000000    1    01/27/16
              U# NUMBER        UNIT #                                FAIL        

JT00000000  DOE, JOHN              01/24/16            J00000000    1    01/28/16


J000000000  DOE, JOHN              01/25/16  01/31/16  J00000000    1    01/29/16 
              TXN MISS         UNIT #                                FAIL
```